# How to set a random number before_save for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Produt model, that if the user left blank, I need to generate a random number. How can I achieve that?

```
  def self.set_random_number()
   if self.code == null
    self.code.rand(1000..99999)
   end
  end
```

I tried this method, and called before_save :set_random_number(). But it doesn't work. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the `code` meant to be unique across all instances of `Product`?

Comment: Yes! Now I'm starting to think about this problem.

Comment: Is the `code` meant to be human-friendly? If not, you might consider using a UUID.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it has to be human-friendly. I'm not dealing with a lot of products, so I think I will randomize for like 1000..1000000, so the odds of getting the same number it's like zero. Not the best solution, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the randon number in the model, change your method to this:

```
before_save :set_random_number

def set_random_number
 self.code = rand(1000..99999) if self.code.blank?
end
```

Comment: So, I did that change. But now I get "undefined method `set_random_number' for #<Product:0x00007fd2f7c31cf8>" when it hits the 'create' action on Products Controller. How can I solve that?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it should not be a class method in the first place. Remove the self from the method name, I'll edit my answer. Sorry!

Comment: `self.set_random_number` is going to create a class method, yes? And you want a instance method, yes? So, `def set_random_number`. Also, it's not very rubyish to have trailing parentheses after a method declaration with no arguments. For the body of the method, how about `self.code ||= rand(1000..99999)`? Saves you twenty taps of the keyboard which over time can save you days of your life.

Comment: It stills get an error with that solution, now it's: "undefined local variable or method `null' for #<Product:0x00007fd2f6c13c40>". I really don't understand why.

Comment: Try `nil` instead of `null`. You could also do `self.code = rand(1000..99999) unless self.code` and avoid the `== nil` comparison altogether.

Comment: Oh sorry folks, this is the most messed up answer I ever gave - I wasn't very thorough here. Of course it should be `nil` in Ruby! Now it should work

Comment: @ jvillian  Fixed, the trailing parentheses, too (I copied the question's code to quickly). 
And of course, for a 10x engineer your option is better, but for a beginner I think it's more readbale/understandable tha way.
Sorry again for the many edits, should be fine now

Comment: It's passing, but when I create/save the object, it doesn't generate a random code. What am I missing?

Comment: It could be, that if you leave the field for `code` empty, that empty strings are passed through the params, so then the cold field is not nil, but `""`. So here we need to change the if statement in the method, to `.blank?` which is true for `nil`, empty strings, empty arrays and so on... I'll adjust my answer once more :D

Comment: You're a genius, it worked! Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Good answers, Clara! And many edits are often a good thing!

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks @jvillian, but normaly I expect myself to catch the small things like `null` and the parentheses. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @frosassss if you could accept my answer, that would be great :)

Comment: @Clara did it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
before_save :set_random_number

def set_random_number
  return if code.present?

  self.code = rand(1000..99999)
end
```

Comment: I believe you'll find, in reading the comments to Clara's answer, that the value is being set to an empty string. So, this won't work, right? Because the empty string will evaluate to non-nil and the `rand` will never be called.